# ASP.NET MVC Web App gets incomplete data from MySQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, mysql-workbench, connection-string

I just developed my first ASP.NET MVC web application. The main function of the page is to view all the data that would come from the database into a table. The data store in my local db is a collection of contact information with name, address, phone number, etc. I actually was able to retrieve the data and view it in a table on my Index page. However, there are some missing data on it.

Here is what my table looked like: [image]

This is my actual database:

[[image]

This is my Contacts model:

```
public class Contacts
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string State { get; set; }
   public string Country { get; set; }
   public int ZipCode { get; set; }
   public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
   public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

For my Controller this is what I had done:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      var data = SQLDataAccess.GetContacts();
      List<Contacts> contacts = new List<Contacts>();

      foreach (var item in data)
      {
          contacts.Add(new Contacts
          {
              FirstName = item.FirstName,
              LastName = item.LastName,
              Address = item.Address,
              State = item.State,
              Country = item.Country,
              ZipCode = item.ZipCode,
              PhoneNumber = item.PhoneNumber,
              Notes = item.Notes
          });
      }
      return View(contacts);
   }
}
```

SQLDataAccess looks like this:

```
public static class SQLDataAccess
{
   public static List<T> GetData<T>(string sql)
   {
      using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; port=3306; Database=testdb; UserId=root; password=123456"))
      {
         connect.Open();
         return connect.Query<T>(sql).ToList();
      }
   }

   public static List<Contacts> GetContacts()
   {
      string select = @"Select * from contacts;";
      return GetData<Contacts>(select);
   }
}
```

Please do copy the cshtml codes here for the View. I hope this is okay.

```html
@model IEnumerable<ContactsTable.Models.Contacts>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Refresh Table", "Index")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ZipCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Notes)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ZipCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notes)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I inserted this line right before the `return` line of the GetData() function under SQLDataAccess class and was able to check through a breakpoint that all 3 data was retrieved, but with the rest of the missing data as NULL.

```
var test = connect.Query<T>(sql);
```

I tried using gridview and retrieve data though DataBind and it works, all data was successfully viewed in the table.

Can someone help me understand why this happened?
Any help would be so much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't shown what Markup you have, but at a glance it looks like you have gotten the Case wrong on some of the properties.

Comment: I was actually using Razor, which was automatically generated when I added the View for Index.

Comment: Pls show us your view code.

Comment: @Sergey I saved my edit just now.

Comment: @Steve THANKS SO MUCH! that saved me :) I'll take note of that from now on.

Comment: Then posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are using Dapper to retrieve your data and put it inside your class. In this case you should know that dapper automatically maps the field names to the property names of the class HAVING THE SAME NAME. Your missing fields all have an _ in them, so dapper cannot transfer those values to your properties.

A simple solution that doesn't involve renaming neither the class properties to match the database fields names or a renaming of the fields names to match the property names or use a mapping code is the following

```
public static List<Contacts> GetContacts()
{
    string select = @"select id, first_name as FirstName, last_name as LastName
                    address, state, country, zip_code as zipcode,
                    phone_number as phonenumber, notes
                    from contacts";
   return GetData<Contacts>(select);
}
```

In this way each different field name is aliased to match the property name and Dapper should be able to fill your class instance fully.

Answer (score 0):

connect.Query(sql,commandType:CommandType.Text).ToList();

also
string select = @"Select * from contacts";

```
  [Display(Name="FirstName")]
   public string first_name { get; set; }
  [Display(Name="LastName")]
   public string last_name{ get; set; }
  [Display(Name="Address")]
   public string address { get; set; }
  [Display(Name="State")]
   public string state { get; set; }
  [Display(Name="ZipCode")]
   public int zipCode { get; set; }
  [Display(Name="PhoneNumber")]
   public string phone_number { get; set;
```